# Use markdown syntax in markdown chunks

Tags: r-markdown, markdown, bookdown

I'm using bookdown to write my math notes, bookdown provide an feature that one can use

````
```{theorem}
{theorem content}
```
````

to write theorems and auto numbered.

However, my preview tool does not realize i'm still wring markdown and the preview will look like

[image]

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Just for the record, this was cross-posted at: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1047

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting cderv](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1047#issuecomment-747956938) in [the issue you reported on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1047):

> There is a new way to write this environment using [custom blocks syntax](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html). It is in [NEWS](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-bookdown-version-021) but not yet documented in the book. Will do soon.
>
> You can use
>
> ```
> ::: {.theorem #label name="name"}
> <any markdown syntax content>
> :::
> ```
>
> It works for HTML and PDF output.
>
> I don't know what "other preview tool" you are referring but the content inside this block will be markdown, so I think it will be better for your usage.
>
> The new RStudio Visual Markdown editor helps a lot to write and see those divs !
> https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/09/30/rstudio-v1-4-preview-visual-markdown-editing/